# Exception: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to loop through elements on the page and then get the text from the element. While getting the text, I am trying to strip a specific word "NEW" and then add it in the list.

Here is my code.

```
def test(self, cardname):

    mylist = []
    allrows = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'scopes-pending-')]")
    count = len(allrows)

    for i in range(count):
        rows = self.driver.find_element_by_id("scopes-" + cardname + "" + str(i) + "").text
        if "NEW" in rows:
            row_split = rows.strip('NEW')
            mylist.append(row_split.text)
        else:
            mylist.append(rows.text)

    return mylist
```

But I am getting this error

```
Exception: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I have tried a bunch of different ways but none of them are working. For example,

```
rows = self.driver.find_element_by_id("scopes-" + cardname + "" + i + "").text
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Exception: must be str, not int
```

It seems like I am missing something very small and need help figuring it out (still new to python). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you want to get right from the very beginning is to use descriptive variable names. This will help you and anyone else that has to read your code understand what you are trying to do.

I changed a few variable names using my best guess at what they were. Obviously feel free to change them to whatever makes sense if I guessed wrong.

`mylist` -> `labelList`

`allrows` -> `rowLabels`

`rows` -> `rowLabel` (singular since it's only one)

Removed some "extra" variables. I tend to not create a new variable if I'm not going to use it again. For example, `count` just holds `len(allrows)`. You can remove `count` and just use `len(allrows)` in the only place it shows up, in the `for` loop.

Removed some extra `""`s you had in your locator, e.g. `...cardname + "" + str(i) + ""`. The `+ "" +` doesn't do anything here since you are just concatenating an empty string `""` so I removed those.

`rows.strip()` will remove the string if the substring exists. If the substring doesn't exist, it just returns the entire string. Since this is the case, you don't need an `if-else`.

The below code is how I would write this.

```
def test(self, cardname):
    labelList = []
    allrows = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'scopes-pending-')]")

    for i in range(len(allrows)):
        rowLabel = self.driver.find_element_by_id("scopes-" + cardname + str(i)).text
        labelList.append(rowLabel.strip('NEW'))

    return labelList
```

Caveat... I'm not a python programmer so there may be some more optimizations and ways to make this code more python-y than I have suggested.

---

As to the errors,

> Exception: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

```
row_split = rows.strip('NEW')
mylist.append(row_split.text)
```

In the above lines, `row_split` is a string and you are doing `<string>.text` which causes the error. `.text` can be used on a Web Element.

> Exception: must be str, not int

```
rows = self.driver.find_element_by_id("scopes-" + cardname + "" + i + "").text
```

You fixed this one already. It's complaining that `i` is an `int` and not a string. `str(i)` fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just appending `row_split`? If it's a `str` object, it likely *is* the text you're looking for (`str` in Python is the string object).

If you added the line you're getting the error on, that'd be helpful too.

My guess is that your first exception is from trying to get the `text` attribute from `row_split` from a string (I assume that the the `text` attribute returned from `self.driver.find_element_by_id` is of type `str`).

And then you get the second exception from trying to concatenate a `str` and an int (that'd be `i`). You were right to cast `i` to a `str`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Appending `rows_split` works great however the row is giving me string similar to "test NEW" and I want to strip the word "NEW" from the string. And you are right for the other ones. I am trying to get string from `self.driver.find_element_by_id`

Comment: @Bubbles are you sure that `strip` is the right method? Documentation (both for your API and for Python) is your friend, why don't you take a look at the docs for `strip` and see how it's used? If it isn't the right method, try Googling (or searching here) for one that does what you want.

Answer (score -1):

I faced same problem

This is my code with solution:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windos NT 6.3; x64) AppleWebkit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36'}

webpage=requests.get('..').text


soup=BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

names = soup.find_all("div",class_="fcab3ed991 a23c043802")

hotel_name=[]

for i in names:
  Name = i.content    # ->  here I use "content" instead of  "text"
  hotel_name.append(Name)
```

**Note**: I do not use a webpage in the soup variable line.