# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text':

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm trying to write a method that looks at all values in a list and confirms that the values in the list match the expected values. I'm getting an AttributeError in my if statement.

```
@step('Confirm sources in the dropdown when uploading a file "{source_list}"')
def step_impl(context, source_list):

 open_list = context.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='id_source']")
    if not open_list:
        raise ValueError('Source dropdown menu not found')
    open_list.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    source_options = context.browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "// *[ @ id = 'id_source']/option")
    for v in source_options:
        source = (v.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
        if source_list in source[0].text:
            print("Verified sources are in source list: ", source_list, "\n")
        else:
            raise ValueError("Source type of '%s' was not found in list" % source_list
```

I have an example in my feature file that contains all values in the list. When I run this now I get

> "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text':

Comment: did u try to print the result in source_options? anyway if source_list is a list in the if statement you should do the opposite, if source_list  in list and not the opposite

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571724/exception-str-object-has-no-attribute-text

Comment: `source = (v.get_attribute('innerHTML'))` this will store the `innerHTML` as a string in  `source` and when you try `source[0].text` the script will throw error as you are trying `.text` method on a string. you should try with `if source_list in source:`. I feel you should do this check with xpath rather doing  a loop.

Comment: I tried this one at first and my raise ValueError was triggered even though the value is in the example and is also in the xpath.

after this line.....  source = (v.get_attribute('innerHTML')) I'd add print(source)... and that printed the expected values

Comment: Is your source_list is a string or list can you confirm

Comment: @KunduK The feature is setup as a Scenario Outline with a list of examples ...i.e the values I'm looking for in the dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplified version with xpath.

```
@step('Confirm sources in the dropdown when uploading a file "{source_list}"')
def step_impl(context, source_list):

    open_list = context.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='id_source']")
    if not open_list:
        raise ValueError('Source dropdown menu not found')
        if open_list.find_element_by_xpath("./option[contains(text(),'" + source_list + "')]"):
            print("Verified sources are in source list: ", source_list, "\n")
        else:
            raise ValueError("Source type of '%s' was not found in list" % source_list
```